# python modifying sys.path doesn't work

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, path

I have a new numpy version under `/opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, and a standard (system) version under `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. I want to temporarily use the new numpy version so I add the following at the beginning of my script:

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: sys.path.insert(1,'/opt/numpy/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

In [3]: sys.path
Out[3]: 
['',
 '/opt/numpy/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/bin',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/extensions']
```

Strangely it still loads the old numpy version:

```
In [4]: import numpy as np

In [5]: np.__file__
Out[5]: '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc'
```

Does anyone has any idea about this?

Note1: This question is about sys.path in python. Please don't recommend me to use virtualenv or change PYTHONPATH.

Note2: the following files are found under my new numpy directory

```
$ ls /opt/numpy/lib/python2.7/site-packages
easy-install.pth  numpy-1.11.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg  __pycache__  site.py  site.pyc
```

Comment: *"Please don't recommend me to use virtualenv"* - why not? That's generally the easiest way to manage a dev environment with specific versions of your requirements.

Comment: What environment are you using, Anaconda's Notebook or IDE?

Comment: @DeepakM it is python and ipython under `/usr/bin/python` and `/usr/local/bin/ipython` respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I have to add the numpy **.egg** file to sys.path in order to make it work.

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: sys.path.insert(1,'/opt/numpy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.11.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg')

In [3]: sys.path
Out[3]: 
['',
 '/opt/numpy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.11.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/bin',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/extensions']

In [4]: import numpy as np

In [5]: np.__file__
Out[5]: '/opt/numpy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.11.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/__init__.pyc'
```

It doesn't work if I add the site-packages only:

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: sys.path.insert(1,'/opt/numpy/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

In [3]: sys.path
Out[3]: 
['',
 '/opt/numpy/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/bin',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/extensions']

In [4]: import numpy as np

In [5]: np.__file__
Out[5]: '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc'
```